# Correct way of receiving Aarti

Tags: belief, rituals, worship, puja

[Aarti(आरती)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aarti) is one of the popular Hindu religious ritual of worship in which light from wicks soaked in ghee (purified butter) or camphor is offered to one or more deities. Aarti also refer to the songs sung in praise of the deity, when lamps are being offered.

When Aarti is done, the priest usually circulates the *Aarti Plate* or *Lamp* to all devotees present right there.

But it seems everyone have their own way of "receiving" this Aarti. Some people cup their down-turned hands over the flame and then raise their palms to their forehead or some other don't cup their hands and just takes it with un-folded palms.

**My Question is** : What is the correct way of receiving/taking/consuming the Aarti as per Hinduism? Are there any scripture which helps disclosing this information?